# Get size of screen without bottom navigation bar height

Tags: flutter

So the basic scaffold in flutter has appbar, body and bottom bar.

in my bottom navigation bar I have 3 items:

1. Page 1 (Editor Page)
2. page 2 (Stickers)
3. page 3 (Text Customization Page)

Each of these pages have their own scaffolds.

Editor page has a widget called LayoutCanvas which is something like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      CanvasModel.of(context).init(canvasKey!);
    });
    return Container(
```

Inside `init`:

```
  void init(GlobalKey canvasKey) {
    _canvasKey = canvasKey;
    final context = _canvasKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) return;
    final bounds = context.findRenderObject()!.paintBounds;

    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    var canvasHeight = screenHeight * 0.7;
    var canvasWidth = layout.aspectRatio * canvasHeight;
```

**Issue:**

As you can see I'm taking 0.7 or 70% of the screen height as the canvas height and calculating the rest from there. But 70% is quite small for something like an editor canvas. But if I make it 80% some of the editor is getting cut by the bottom navigation bar.

Maybe the `screenHeight` is not taking the bottom navigation bar height into consideration?

I either need to make it dynamic or I need to subtract the bottom nav height from `screenHeight`.

**aspectRatio:**

`double get aspectRatio => isInitialized ? height / _layout!.height : 0;`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to get height of bottom navigation bar and substract it from screenHeight variable so that you can find canvasHeight variable.

Comment: You can try `LayoutBuilder` for inner body

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the maximum available height you need to subtract some values from `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`. Assuming that you have a top `AppBar` and a `BottomNavigationBar`, you can use this formula:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -    // total height 
  kToolbarHeight -                      // top AppBar height
  MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -  // top padding
  kBottomNavigationBarHeight            // BottomNavigationBar height
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks

Comment: Happy to hear, you are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).